# Autofill text box after select from dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my html from I used a  tag from fetch data from database table and store data to another table.my code is :

```
       <select class="form-control" name="name" required> 
<option value="0">Please Select Hotel</option>
    <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get))
        {
        ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo($row['name'])?>" >
            <?php echo($row['name']) ?>
        </option>
        <?php

        }               
    ?>
</select>
```

I want to add a text fill below that select option where data will be auto field from database after select from drop down.My code is :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username" value="<?php echo($row['username']) ?>" disabled required />
```

But after submit from , no data is stored from autofill text box

Comment: Do you want to fill the `name="username"` with value which is selected in above dropdown?

Comment: I didn't get where would you put the input field, is it under the `select` tag ? Or under each `option` tag you put an input field (that looks weird though as of `select` tag can only have `option` tags in it) ?

Answer (score 1):

From the title "Autofill text box after select from dropdown", I think you have to place the value of selected option to a input field. If so, you need to use `JS` or `jQuery`.

If I'm correct, you can check the below code:

```js
// Pure JS

document.getElementById("selectname").onchange = function() {
  var e = document.getElementById("selectname");
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("username").value = strUser;
};

// jQuery

$('body').on('change', '#selectname', function() {
$('#username2').val($('#selectname option:selected').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name" id="selectname">
  <option value="User 1">User 1</option>
  <option value="User 2">User 2</option>
  <option value="User 3">User 3</option>
  <option value="User 4">User 4</option>
  <option value="User 5">User 5</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username" id="username" value="" disabled required />

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" name="username2" id="username2" value="" disabled required />
```

There are 2 section of code one for `JS` & other with `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Please take note of the spelling of `from` and `form` as mixing both up in your code will not work.

Add form tags to your select / drop down box if you wish to get the value.

```
   <form action="" method="POST">
    <select class="form-control" name="hotelName" required> 
      <option value="0">Please Select Hotel</option>
        <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get))
            {
                echo "<option value ='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
            }               
        ?>
    </select>
   <form>
```

leaving the `action=""` submits the form to the same page if it's being sent to another page then add the page link there.

`method="POST"` submits the form with a `post request` if you wish to use a `get request` then change it to `method="GET"`

grab the user input with `$_POST['hotelName']` or `$_GET['hotelName']`

also remember to always perform validation on all user inputs and use bindParam on it before saving to database better still use use `PDO`